# error: no matching function for call to ‘PSTUNClient::PSTUNClient

Tags: c++, linux, centos, fedora, opalvoip

This following code always throwing same error, it seems to be working in ubuntu, but not in fedora/centos.

```
2945 void H323EndPoint::SetSTUNServer(const PString & server)
2946 {
2947   natMethods->RemoveMethod("STUN");
2948   delete stun;
2949 
2950   if (server.IsEmpty())
2951     stun = NULL;
2952   else {
2953     stun = new PSTUNClient(server,
2954                            GetUDPPortBase(), GetUDPPortMax(),
2955                            GetRtpIpPortBase(), GetRtpIpPortMax());
2956 
2957     natMethods->AddMethod(stun);
2958 
2959     PTRACE(2, "H323\tSTUN server \"" << server 
              << "\" replies " << stun->GetNatTypeName());
2960 
2961         STUNNatType((int)stun->GetNatType());
2962   }
2963 }
2964 
2965 #endif // P_STUN
```

Steps tried:

```
$ cd ~
$ cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@openh323gk.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/openh323gk login
(just press enter when prompted for password)
$ cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@openh323gk.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/openh323gk co -P openh323gk
$ cd openh323gk
$ ./configure --enable-h46018
$ make optnoshared
make DEBUG= P_SHAREDLIB=0 default_target
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/h323plus'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/h323plus'
make -C src optnoshared
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/h323plus/src'
make DEBUG= P_SHAREDLIB=0 default_target
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/h323plus/src'
[CC] h323ep.cxx
h323ep.cxx: In member function ‘PBoolean H323EndPoint::StartListeners(const H323TransportAddressArray&)’:
h323ep.cxx:1107:29: warning: ‘virtual PObject* PAbstractList::RemoveAt(PINDEX)’ is deprecated (declared at /root/ptlib/include/ptlib/lists.h:233)
h323ep.cxx: In member function ‘PBoolean H323EndPoint::RemoveAliasName(const PString&)’:
h323ep.cxx:2750:31: warning: ‘virtual PObject* PAbstractList::RemoveAt(PINDEX)’ is deprecated (declared at /root/ptlib/include/ptlib/lists.h:233)
h323ep.cxx: In member function ‘void H323EndPoint::SetSTUNServer(const PString&)’:
h323ep.cxx:2955:65: error: no matching function for call to ‘PSTUNClient::PSTUNClient(const PString&, WORD, WORD, WORD, WORD)’
/root/ptlib/include/ptclib/pstun.h:441:5: note: candidates are: PSTUNClient::PSTUNClient()
/root/ptlib/include/ptclib/pstun.h:438:1: note:                 PSTUNClient::PSTUNClient(const PSTUNClient&)
/root/ptlib/include/ptlib/sound.h: At global scope:
/root/ptlib/include/ptlib/sound.h:745:1: warning: ‘PPlugin_PSoundChannel_WAVFile_loader’ defined but not used
/root/ptlib/include/ptlib/videoio.h:1165:1: warning: ‘PPlugin_PVideoInputDevice_FakeVideo_loader’ defined but not used
/root/ptlib/include/ptlib/videoio.h:1172:1: warning: ‘PPlugin_PVideoInputDevice_FFMPEG_loader’ defined but not used
/root/ptlib/include/ptlib/videoio.h:1176:1: warning: ‘PPlugin_PVideoInputDevice_YUVFile_loader’ defined but not used
/root/h323plus/include/h460/h460_std18.h:119:1: warning: ‘PPlugin_H460_Feature_Std18_loader’ defined but not used
/root/h323plus/include/h460/h460_std18.h:179:1: warning: ‘PPlugin_H460_Feature_Std19_loader’ defined but not used
/root/h323plus/include/h460/h46018_h225.h:377:1: warning: ‘PPlugin_PNatMethod_H46019_loader’ defined but not used
/root/h323plus/include/h460/h460_std23.h:194:1: warning: ‘PPlugin_H460_Feature_Std23_loader’ defined but not used
/root/h323plus/include/h460/h460_std23.h:278:1: warning: ‘PPlugin_H460_Feature_Std24_loader’ defined but not used
/root/h323plus/include/h460/h460_std9.h:113:1: warning: ‘PPlugin_H460_Feature_Std9_loader’ defined but not used
/root/h323plus/include/h460/h460_oid3.h:181:1: warning: ‘PPlugin_H460_Feature_OID3_loader’ defined but not used
/root/h323plus/include/gnugknat.h:304:1: warning: ‘PPlugin_PNatMethod_GnuGk_loader’ defined but not used
/root/ptlib/include/ptlib/pluginmgr.h:167:1: warning: ‘PFactoryLoader::PluginLoaderStartup_loader’ defined but not used
/root/ptlib/include/ptclib/url.h:479:1: warning: ‘PFactoryLoader::PURL_HttpLoader_loader’ defined but not used
/root/ptlib/include/ptclib/url.h:482:1: warning: ‘PFactoryLoader::PURL_FtpLoader_loader’ defined but not used
make[2]: *** [/root/h323plus/lib/obj_s/h323ep.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/h323plus/src'
make[1]: *** [optnoshared] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/h323plus/src'
make: *** [optnoshared] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that it can't find a constructor for the `PSTUNClient` class with the prototype `PSTUNClient::PSTUNClient(const PString&, WORD, WORD, WORD, WORD)`.

These are the pertinent lines in the error output:

```
h323ep.cxx:2955:65: error: no matching function for call to ‘PSTUNClient::PSTUNClient(const PString&, WORD, WORD, WORD, WORD)’
/root/ptlib/include/ptclib/pstun.h:441:5: note: candidates are: PSTUNClient::PSTUNClient()
/root/ptlib/include/ptclib/pstun.h:438:1: note:                 PSTUNClient::PSTUNClient(const PSTUNClient&)
```

In your code, this line:

```
stun = new PSTUNClient(server,
                       GetUDPPortBase(), GetUDPPortMax(),
                       GetRtpIpPortBase(), GetRtpIpPortMax());
```

...is the one causing the error.

You're probably trying to use a constructor that doesn't exist. The compiler is hinting that you use `PSTUNClient::PSTUNClient()` instead.

i.e.

```
stun = new PSTUNClient();
```

If this compiles in your ubuntu build but not fedora, ask yourself if you're using the same version of the PSTUN library in both builds.

Comment: +1 mostly for the last paragraph. The rest of the answer gives the proper lead-up context.